# Calculate the integral $\int_0^1 \sum_{r_n \leq x} 2^{-n} dx$

Tags: integration, measure-theory

Let $(r_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ be an enumeration of all rational numbers in interval $(0,1)$. I want to calculate the integral

$$ \int_0^1 f(x) dx = \int_0^1 \sum_{r_n \leq  x}\frac{1}{2^n}dx =  \int_0^1\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^n}\chi_{(r_n  \leq x)}dx$$

I'm aware that both $2^{-n}$ and $\chi_{(r_n  \leq x)}$ are measurable, so $2^{-n} \chi_{(r_n <x)}$ is measurable aswell. Since both of them are bounded above on the interval $[0,1]$, we can use Lebesgue's DCT. So my idea is that

\begin{align}
\int_0^1\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^n}\chi_{(r_n \leq x)}dx =& \int_0^1 \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{2^n}\chi_{(r_n \leq x)}dx\\
&= \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \int_0^1 \sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{2^n}\chi_{(r_n \leq  x)}dx\\
&= \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{n=1}^{N} \int_0^1\frac{1}{2^n}\chi_{(r_n \leq  x)}dx\\
&= \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{2^n} \int_0^1\chi_{(r_n \leq  x)}dx\\
\end{align}

But I dont know how to compute the last integral. Appriciating all help I can get.

Thank in advance.

**Edit**: I accidently had [0,1] on first row when it should have been (0,1).

**Edit2**:

I came up with the perhaps-solution that $$ \int_0^1\chi_{(r_n \leq x)}dx = \int_{r_n}^1dx = 1-r_n$$ since the integral depend on how the $r_n$ are chosen, but I'm not sure if this is correct...

**Edit3**: Realized I had written < when correct was $\leq$.

Comment: Are you aware that the value of the integral will depend of the particular choice of the enumeration?

Comment: @jjagmath I believe so, yes, and that's what makes me confused. I can't see how the integral should be computed as the result depends on how r_n is chosen.

Comment: @jjagmath I might have solved it. Would it be correct to basically remove the indicator function and edit the limits of the integrals as r_n to 1 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a discussion with my friends, we conclude that $$ \int_0^1\chi_{(r_n \leq x)}dx = \int_{r_n}^1dx = 1 - r_n$$ and thus, we have $$ \int_0^1\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^n}\chi_{(r_n \leq x)}dx = \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{2^n} (1 - r_n) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1 - r_n}{2^n}$$
which can't be further simplified, since the value of $r_n$ depends on how we order the rational numbers.